# How do I loop over another loop to fill a matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a loop that works completely well by itself. What I essentially want to do is repeat that same loop 100 more times to fill a matrix that 100x bigger than the original matrix.

```
nsite - 267
nyear - 14
#pred.occ is a data.frame of 14 columns and 267 rows 
z_pred <- array(NA, dim = c(nsite, 4*100)) # my matrix
for (i in 1:100) {  
# Generate presence/absence (i.e., the truth) in subsequent years
for(t in 11:nyear){
  z_pred[,t*i] <- rbinom(n = nsite, size = 1, prob = pred.occ[,11:nyear])
}
sum_occupancy <- apply(z_pred, 2, sum) / nsite # predicted occupancy proportion
}
```

The error I am getting is "subscript out of bounds" but I tried to modify but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: `rbinom(n=267,size=1, prob=pred.occ[,11:14])` is failing because you are passing a dataframe of `dim=267,3` to the `prob` parameter.

Comment: But the dimensions are like this
`str(pred.occ[,11:nyear]) `
 num [1:267, 1:4]

Comment: yes, i mean 267,4.  But you need to pass a vector of probabilities to the prob argument, not a dataframe of shape 267,4

Comment: I tried converting it into vector like this 
`pred.occ_vector <- as.vector(pred.occ[,11:nyear])` then using pred.occ_vector in prob argument but it still shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a number of things going on here.

1. First, your matrix z_pred has dimensions 267,400, but your call in the innermost loop tries to assign to columns of this matrix that don't exist. For example, when `t=11` and `i=40` you will try to assign to column 440.
2. You are trying to pass a dataframe of size 267x4 to the prob param of the rbinom function. I think what you want to do here is pass the 267 probabilities in column `t`

Here is a revised version that might help you

```
z_pred <- array(NA, dim = c(nsite, 4*100)) # my matrix
for (i in 1:100) {  
  # Generate presence/absence (i.e., the truth) in subsequent years
  for(t in 11:nyear) {
    z_pred[,100*(t-11) + i] <- rbinom(n = nsite, size = 1, prob =pred.occ[,t])
  }
  sum_occupancy <- apply(z_pred, 2, sum) / nsite # predicted occupancy proportion
}
```